# Mongoose - Nest schemas without refs?

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have an app with Transactions (bank transactions) and RepeatingTransactions (e.g. to automatically pay your bills every month). I want to define a RepeatingTransaction Schema which has a base Transaction field which it can copy to the Transaction collection every time it has to be done. I don't want to do this with references since the app uses the Transactions collection in other parts of the app. (I spent some time figuring out the business logic and this is good this way, I don't want to change it).

The ideal case would be if there was a way to nest my Transaction schema to the RepeatingTransaction to avoid code duplication.

So is there a way to nest schemas without reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this simply. Just nest your Schema inside your other Schema, it will work fine.

What I did wrong was that I tried to put a Model inside my schema. To solve the problem easily in my `./model` folder I have a Transaction model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const TransactionSchema = require('./schemas/transaction-schema');

TransactionSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    this.createdAt = new Date();
    next();
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Transaction', TransactionSchema
```

);

And a RepeatingTransaction model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const TransactionSchema = require('./schemas/transaction-schema');

let RepeatingTransactionSchema = new Schema({
    user: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    transaction: {type: TransactionSchema, required: [true, 'Transation is required']},
    period: {type: String, required: [true, 'Interval is required']},
    nextDate: {type: Date, required: [true, 'Date is required']}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('RepeatingTransaction', RepeatingTransactionSchema);
```

And of course there is a TransactionSchema too:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let TransactionSchema = new Schema({
    ...
});

module.exports = TransactionSchema;
```